# problems in request in unit test the status is undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am trying to do a unit test to an action in my react application but apparently everything works fine, I get a message that I am not understanding when making the request and the status is undefined, I don't have any specific variable with the status name so I assume it must be a problem when making the promise. How can I solve this problem?

> error : undefined | TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of
> undefined
> at request (C:\Users\amils\OneDrive\Documentos\Bootcamp - Training\Project\tracking-tool-webapp\src\api\utilities\fetch.js:45:26)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at Object.getAll (C:\Users\amils\OneDrive\Documentos\Bootcamp -
> Training\Project\tracking-tool-webapp\src\api\utilities\provider.js:18:9)

console log result:

```
console.log
      [
        {
          title: 'Candidates',
          errorMessages: [],
          candidates: [],
          reports: null,
          loading: false,
          programsInProgress: [],
          programVersions: [],
          statusType: []
        },
        { onLoadCandidates: [Function: onLoadCandidates] }
      ]
```

The code:

```
it('Should get all candidates', async () => {
            const mockResponse = {
                candidates: [
                    {
                        id: '4fffc534-1d83-14d5-b264-1e17f2abd322',
                        name: 'Homer Simpson',
                        status: 'InProgress',
                    },
                    {
                        id: '4fffc535-1d83-14d5-b264-1e17f2abd322',
                        name: 'Junior Santos',
                        status: 'InProgress',
                    },
                ],
            };

            global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
                Promise.resolve({
                    status: 200,
                    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse),
                });
            });

            const result = await customRenderHook();
            const actions = result.current[1];
            console.log(result);
            await act(async () => {
                actions.onLoadCandidates();
            });

            const state = result.current[0];
            expect(state.candidates).toEqual(mockResponse);
        });
```

code customRenderHook:

```
const customRenderHook = () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => <CandidatesDataProvider>{children}</CandidatesDataProvider>;
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useCandidatesContext(), { wrapper });
    return result;
};
```

I find the problem, currently, I cant execure my promise without a tokes 'Bearer', now the problem here is how can I create a mock of token:

```
function onLoadCandidates(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.loading, payload: true });

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    apiCandidate
        .getAll(token)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.loading, payload: response.data });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.Error, payload: err.message });
            LoggerService.error(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.loading, payload: false });
        });
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of the `customRenderHook`

Comment: @slideshowp2 I leave the code of customRenderHook

Answer (score 0):

You could mock `localStorage.getItem` to return a token in the format required by `apiCandidate.getAll(token)`:

```js
localStorage.getItem = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('your-token');
```

Comment: continue like undefined

Comment: Where did you place the mock statement? It should go before `const result = await customRenderHook()` .

Comment: Also, take a look at `apiCandidate.getAll(token)` and see what `getAll` expects the `token` param to be.